# PHP Class variable access question

Tags: php, class

I'm having trouble accessing a class' variable.

I have the functions below in the class.

```
class Profile { 

    var $Heading;

    // ...

    function setPageTitle($title)
    {
        $this->Heading = $title;
        echo 'S: ' . $this->Heading;
    }

    function getPageTitle2()
    {       
        echo 'G: ' . $this->Heading;
        return $this->Heading;
    }

// ...
}
```

Now when I run the method `$this->setPageTitle("test")` I only get

`G: S: test`

What's wrong with the `getPageTitle2` function? Heading is public btw. Please help!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please provide code which call the methods.

Comment: the whole code is located at www.fearghal.com/Untitled-1.phps 

the function names are SetContent() and getPageContents() ... they called the functions is questions.

Answer (score 4):

> Now when I run the method `$this->setPageTitle("test")` I only get
>
> `G: S: test`

That sounds implausible. Are you sure you're not running:

```
$this->getPageTitle2();
$this->setPageTitle("test");
```

PHP - like most programming languages - is an imperative language. This means that the order in which you do things matters. The variable `$this->Header` is not set at the time where you call `getPageTitle2`.

Comment: well i have other functions 

//(the only one that calls the set function)
function getPageContents() 
{
$this->setPageTitle("test");
}

and the other

function setContent // runs the getPageTitle2
{
echo '<div id="page_title">'.$this->getPageTitle2().'</div>';
}

so i didn't think it mattered the placement of functions within a class. Perhaps the getPageContents() must be placed above the Set()?

Comment: @Fergs Placement of the method in the class doesn't matter, this I can guarantee.  Somewhere in your code, you are explicitly calling getPageTitle2(), before you call setPageTitle() - there is no implicit or otherwise automagical way to call a method named getPageTitle2.

Comment: thats what i figured: i;ve uploaded the code to 

www.fearghal.com/Untitled-1.phps

Its semi large but the SetContent and getPageContents are in there and call the functions in question...could you have a look?

Comment: @fergs That code is just a class. It won't do anything at all. Your problem likely lies in the code that *uses* the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "G: S: test"
it means you called getPageTitle2 before setPageTitle !
It looks normal then : I suggest first set then get.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the Heading and title out of the function ... i dont know if you already did that

see the order of calling the functions

Comment: yes, my class starts like:

class Profile 
{
  var $Heading;

but does $title need to as well even though its feed straight into the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Profile { 

var $Heading;

// ...

function setPageTitle($title)
{
    $this->Heading = $title;
    echo 'S: ' . $this->Heading;
}

function getPageTitle2()
{       
    echo 'G: ' . $this->Heading;
    return $this->Heading;
}

// ...
}
```

I am guessing you are doing something like this:

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->setPageTitle("test");
$profile->getPageTitle2();
```

and that this would result in the following output:

```
S: testG: test
```

and that if you `echo $profile` you will just get

```
test
```

so what do you think is the problem or what are you not accomplishing that you want to?

also I would probably declare `$Heading` as

```
private $heading;
```